# install docker-cloud client using pip

Tags: linux, pip, docker-cloud

Hi everyone i'm trying to install docker-cloud cli in ubuntu 14:10 using 'pip install docker-cloud' but i'm receiving the error below any idea ?

copying lib/yaml/resolver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/yaml
  copying lib/yaml/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/yaml
  running build_ext
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  checking if libyaml is compilable
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.o
  checking if libyaml is linkable
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.o -lyaml -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml
  building '_yaml' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ext/_yaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext/_yaml.o
  ext/_yaml.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Failed building wheel for PyYAML
  Running setup.py clean for PyYAML
Failed to build PyYAML
Installing collected packages: PyYAML, docker-cloud
  Found existing installation: PyYAML 3.11
    Uninstalling PyYAML-3.11:
      Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-3.11
  Running setup.py install for PyYAML ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-Qc5w69/PyYAML/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KMwbAU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I faced the same issue when installing *googleads*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

The error `No such file or directory #include "Python.h"` is your clue -- it's telling you that you need the Python headers, which are part of the dev package.